# Sort list of CSV in a folder that contain 10k+ files faster

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file, sorting

Hi I'm a newbie in Python and in coding in general. this is my very first post.

I am trying to open and concatenate the last 20 files into a dataframe.

I am succesuful in doing so when i am working with a test folder that contain only 100 files, but as soon as i try my code in the real folder that contain 10k files my code is very slow and take like 5 minutes to finish.

Here is my try :

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import os

path = r'K:/industriel/abc/03_LOG/PRODUCTION/CSV/'

path2 = r'K:/industriel/abc/03_LOG/PRODUCTION/IMG/'

os.chdir(path)
files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
#files = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(path))
files = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in files]
files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getctime(x), reverse=False)
dfs = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(20):
    dfs = dfs.append(pd.read_csv(files[i].split('\\')[-1],delimiter=';', usecols=[0,1,3,4,9,10,20]))

dfs = dfs.reset_index(drop=True)

print(dfs.head(10))
```

Comment: Don't `append` to dataframes in a loop; it'll force a copy of the whole df memory each time. That doesn't answer your actual question (which might not need appends at all) but, if you need to append, collect the dfs in a list and do `append` in a single call

Comment: It isn't a surprise that more files take more time, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading all the individual files to a `list` and then `concat` to form your dataframe at the end:

```
files = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith(".csv")]
files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getctime(x), reverse=False)
dfs = list()
for i, file in enumerate(files[:20]):
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=';', usecols=[0,1,3,4,9,10,20]))
dfs = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, So i just tried your solution, it has the same behavior, when it face a folder with 10k files it does take a very long time.

Comment: Edit: after further analysis it is faster by a factor 2. 
but i still find it slow, i mean it is just sorting and selecting n files to append... it shouldn't take 3 minutes to do that... no ?

Comment: The slowest part is probably the reading of the Excel files to dataframes. I doubt the sorting takes much time at all. Your Excel files are probably very large?

Comment: 2k to 6k rows, i dont think that is the problem? because if i append 2 files or 20 it takes roughly the same time

Comment: I removed the usecols and doesnt increase speed :(

Comment: Oof. Last attempt, try: `dfs = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=';', usecols=[0,1,3,4,9,10,20]) for file in files[:20])`

Comment: So I tried again the code at work, and it was 45 seconds instead of the several minutes. so it did help thank you ! and i believe the problem was more on the fact that i was using my work vpn to read the files. 
I still think 45 seconds is slow but at least it's usable now thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use pd.concat() with a list of read files. You can replace your code after files.sort(...) with the following

```
dfs = pd.concat([
    pd.read_csv(files[i].split('\\')[-1], delimiter=';',  usecols=[0,1,3,4,9,10,20])
    for file in files[20:]
])
dfs = dfs.reset_index(drop=True)
print(dfs.head(10))
```